# Kerberized Apache Kafka consumer not creating groups

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kerberos, producer-consumer

I am using version 2.13. Kafka is able to produce messages but not able to consume messages after investigation I found that consumer groups are not getting created and hence the issue.
I am able to consume using partition and offset option but not with group option.

Kafka is kerberized, I am trying to produce messages using following command and this works fine

```
export KRB5CCNAME=/home/kafka/krb5cc;KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true"; 
./kafka-console-producer.sh --producer.config ../config/producer.properties  --topic kerbtopic4 --bootstrap-server kafka:6092
```

Consumer command this works fine but cannot read messages

```
export KRB5CCNAME=/home/kafka/krb5cc;KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true"; 
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --consumer.config ../config/sasl.properties  --topic kerbtopic4 --bootstrap-server ddr-kafka:6092 --from-beginning
```

Consumer command this works fine and can read messages when I give partition and offset

```
export KRB5CCNAME=/home/kafka/krb5cc;KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true"; 
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --consumer.config ../config/sasl.properties  --topic kerbtopic4 --bootstrap-server kafka:6092 --partition 0 --offset earliest
```

This command does not return any group

```
export KRB5CCNAME=/home/kafka/krb5cc;KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true"; 
 ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:6092 --list --command-config ../config/consumer.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue with configuration.
I had to re-install kafka in a different folder and that resolved the issue.
So not sure what caused the issue and how did kafka setup get corrupted such that consumer was unable to create group.